# ASP.NET core 5: Localizing Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-identity

I want to have my ASP.NET Core 5 web app to be globalized with Cookies.
(I suppose) I did everything to be localized:

In Startup:

```
        public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
        {
            services.AddLocalization( options => options.ResourcesPath = "Properties" );
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>( options =>
                {
                    options.SupportedCultures = new[]
                        {
                            new CultureInfo( "en" ),
                            new CultureInfo( "fr" )
                        };
                    options.SupportedUICultures = options.SupportedCultures;
                    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture( "en" );
                } );
            services.AddMvc()
                    .AddViewLocalization( LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix )
                    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

And:

```
public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env )
{
  ...
  app.UseRouting();

  var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
  app.UseRequestLocalization( locOptions.Value );**

  app.UseAuthentication();
  ...
```

It works very well for my own pages (for example Privacy.cshtml or Privacy.fr.cshtml is displayed according to the cookie).

I scaffolded Identity. Translated all Areas\Identity\Pages*.cshtml but they always display in English, whatever the cookie is!

Why does it work for my own views, not for Identity? Is there any thing special to do for Areas?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Hi @Ludovic Dubois,you need write a service which can be used in the Page views to localize the texts.For more details you can see this [article](https://damienbod.com/2018/07/03/adding-localization-to-the-asp-net-core-identity-pages/).

Comment: That's what I did, but does not work. field labels are translated, but the right page is not used.